# Find a Gmail attachment by size

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I am searching a mailbox for the mail that first brought a specific attachment. Since the original mail, the attachment has been saved to associated Google Drive and likely been renamed too.

Since it has been renamed, `filename:CurrentFileName.pdf` searches don't find my document under the filename I know. The only thing I can think of that is likely not to have changed is the file size (PDF files should not change size).

**In short**: It's easy to search the mailbox by *email size* (`size:`) but what about attachment size? Is there a syntax like `attachment:size`?

**Side note**: a search by email size within a 5kB range around the file size found nothing, most probably because the original mail has several files attached.

Comment: If it's a big attachment, have a look at https://www.findbigmail.com. Otherwise, Gmail can find text in the attachment, I think. Is there a unique phrase you can search on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no search filter for attachment size (though that would make a good [feature request](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/V_U7zBUZ8G4)).

The closest you'll likely be able to get is to use several search parameters to try to find a group of emails that might contain the one you're looking for.  You could try:

```
has:attachment filename:pdf larger:{minSize}
```

Replace `{minSize}` with a size that you know is smaller than the attachment.

If you have any idea when the email was sent, you can include an `after:` or `before:` filter -- or both -- to narrow it down even further.

If you remember at least part of the file name, you can use wildcards in your search. For example, you could search for `filename:report*.pdf` or `filename:*report*.pdf`.

Other filters can be added, depending on any other information you might have, such as the sender's name, whether the email was marked as "important," etc.

Comment: Sent a feature request. See what they do with it. Thanks for your help